Issue while conversion of pcd to depth image and back to pcd
I hope you all are doing well.
Currently I am working with pcd. To convert the pcd to depth image and back to pcd. The issue which I am facing is that when I convert the pcd to depth image and back to pcd. The reconstructed pcd are missing the some layers of point clouds, but the depth image are looking good.
Anyone can suggest any technique to handle this issue.
I am attaching the results of my code.Original and reconstructed pcd red color for the original pcd and green color are the reconstructed.
Link for the depth image. Depth image before and after applying mask
My main goal is to got the proper reconstructed point clouds. But the problem is that it is missing some points while reconstructed.
# Code 

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

from pypcd4 import PointCloud

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import open3d as o3d

import os


# Defined parameters

vfov = [-10, 10]            # Vertical field of view in degrees

hfov = [-60, 60]            # Horizontal field of view in degrees

size = [360, 880]           # Size of the depth image (height, width)

depth_scale = 7.97          # Scale factor for depth values

log_scale = True  

def pcd2range_scala3(pcd):

    """
    Conversion of point cloud to depth image using Scala3 projection.
    """

    fov_up = np.deg2rad(vfov[1])  # Field of view up in radians

    fov_down = np.deg2rad(vfov[0])  # Field of view down in radians

    fov_range = fov_up - fov_down  # Total field of view in radians

    # Get depth (distance) of all points

    depth = np.linalg.norm(pcd, axis=1)

    print(f"Depth range before filtering: min={np.min(depth)}, max={np.max(depth)}")

    # Mask points out of range

    mask = np.logical_and(depth > 0, depth < 200)
    depth, pcd = depth[mask], pcd[mask]

    # Get scan components
    scan_x, scan_y, scan_z = pcd[:, 0], pcd[:, 1], pcd[:, 2]

    # Calculate yaw and pitch angles
    yaw = np.arctan2(scan_y, scan_x)
    pitch = np.arcsin(scan_z / depth)

    # Get projections in image coordinates
    proj_x = (yaw - np.deg2rad(hfov[0])) / np.deg2rad(hfov[1] - hfov[0])
    proj_y = (pitch - np.deg2rad(vfov[0])) / (fov_range)
    
    # Scale to image size
    proj_x *= size[1]  # Width
    proj_y *= size[0]  # Height

    # Round and clamp for use as index
    proj_x = np.clip(np.floor(proj_x).astype(int), 0, size[1] - 1)
    proj_y = np.clip(np.floor(proj_y).astype(int), 0, size[0] - 1)

    # Order by decreasing depth
    order = np.argsort(depth)[::-1]
    proj_x, proj_y = proj_x[order], proj_y[order]
    depth = depth[order]

    # Project depth
    proj_range = np.full(size, -1, dtype=np.float32)
    proj_range[proj_y, proj_x] = depth

    # Apply transformation
    if log_scale:
        proj_range = np.log2(proj_range + 1e-3 + 1)  # Added a small epsilon
        proj_range = proj_range / depth_scale
        proj_range = proj_range * 2. - 1.

    print(f"Depth image range after transformation: min={np.min(proj_range)}, max={np.max(proj_range)}")

    return proj_range




def range2pcd_scala3(range_img):


    """
    Conversion of depth image back to point cloud using Scala3 projection.
    """

    fov_up = np.deg2rad(vfov[1])  # Field of view up in radians

    fov_down = np.deg2rad(vfov[0])  # Field of view down in radians

    fov_range = fov_up - fov_down  # Total field of view in radians
    size_range = range_img.shape

    # Inverse transform from depth
    depth = (range_img + 1.) / 2.
    depth = (depth * depth_scale).flatten()
    depth = np.exp2(depth) - 1

    print(f"Reconstructed depth range: min={np.min(depth)}, max={np.max(depth)}")

    # Compute image coordinates
    scan_x, scan_y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(size_range[1]), np.arange(size_range[0]))
    scan_x = scan_x.astype(np.float64) / size_range[1]
    scan_y = scan_y.astype(np.float64) / size_range[0]

    yaw = (scan_x * np.deg2rad(hfov[1] - hfov[0]) + np.deg2rad(hfov[0])).flatten()
    pitch = (scan_y * fov_range + np.deg2rad(vfov[0])).flatten()

    pcd = np.zeros((len(yaw), 3))
    pcd[:, 0] = np.cos(yaw) * np.cos(pitch) * depth
    pcd[:, 1] = np.sin(yaw) * np.cos(pitch) * depth
    pcd[:, 2] = np.sin(pitch) * depth

    # Mask out invalid points
    mask = np.logical_and(depth > 0, depth < 200)
    pcd = pcd[mask, :]

    return pcd


def save_pcd_file(pcd, file_path):

    """
    Save the point cloud to a .pcd file.
    """
    rgb = np.ones((pcd.shape[0], 1)) * [0.7]  # Simple gray color for visualization
    pcd_with_rgb = np.hstack((pcd, rgb))  # Add RGB to point cloud

    pc = PointCloud.from_xyzi_points(pcd_with_rgb)
    pc.save(file_path)

def visualize_point_clouds(pcd1, pcd2, title1='Point Cloud 1', title2='Point Cloud 2'):

    """
    Visualize two point clouds side by side using Open3D.
    """

    # Create point clouds
    point_cloud1 = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    point_cloud1.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(pcd1)
    point_cloud1.paint_uniform_color([1, 0, 0])  # Red for the original

    point_cloud2 = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    point_cloud2.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(pcd2)
    point_cloud2.paint_uniform_color([0, 1, 0])  # Green for the reconstructed

    # Visualize together
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([point_cloud1, point_cloud2],
                                      zoom=0.3412,
                                      front=[0.4257, -0.2125, -0.8795],
                                      lookat=[2.6172, 2.0475, 1.532],
                                      up=[-0.0694, -0.9768, 0.2024])




if __name__ == "__main__":

    input_path = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/cutting_fov/updated_code/input/880x360/07_3.pcd")
    output_path = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/cutting_fov/updated_code/output/800x320/07_3_reconstructed.pcd")

    # Load the point cloud
    pcd = PointCloud.from_path(input_path)
    df_pcd = pd.DataFrame(pcd.pc_data)
    arr_pcd = df_pcd.to_numpy()

    points = arr_pcd.astype(np.float32) + 1e-8

    # Load xyz coordinates
    xyz = points[:, :3]

    # Convert to depth image before applying the FOV mask
    proj_range_before = pcd2range_scala3(xyz)

    # Define the FOV mask
    mask_y = np.zeros(size[0], dtype=bool)
    mask_y[40:320] = True
    mask_x = np.zeros(size[1], dtype=bool)
    mask_x[80:800] = True

    # Apply the FOV mask
    mask = np.outer(mask_y, mask_x)

    # Convert to depth image after applying the FOV mask
    proj_range_after = np.where(mask, proj_range_before, -1)

    # Normalize proj_range for visualization
    proj_range_display_before = np.clip((proj_range_before + 1) / 2, 0, 1)
    proj_range_display_after = np.clip((proj_range_after + 1) / 2, 0, 1)

    # Display depth images
    plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.imshow(proj_range_display_before, cmap='jet', interpolation='nearest')
    plt.title('Depth Image Before Applying Mask')

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.imshow(proj_range_display_after, cmap='jet', interpolation='nearest')
    plt.title('Depth Image After Applying Mask')

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

    # Convert depth image back to point cloud
    pcd_reconstructed = range2pcd_scala3(proj_range_after)

    # Save the reconstructed point cloud
    save_pcd_file(pcd_reconstructed, output_path)

    # Visualize the original and reconstructed point clouds
    visualize_point_clouds(xyz, pcd_reconstructed, title1='Original Point Cloud', title2='Reconstructed Point Cloud')


Please share your code (that is relevant to the problem). You are applying a mask to the depth image, so would you not expect that some points are removed?

I am not considering that point where I applied the mask. If you look at the pcd figure. You will notice that especially for green one, in the start it was ok but then at some points it missed some layers of pcd. On that area you will see the original once which are red.
Let me share the code for the better understanding

The thing which I noticed it is happening because of conversion process, not for applying the mask. I also tried this to remove the masking.
